# Getting the error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'" when implementing Atari Breakout

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I have made a code to solve Atari Breakout. I am facing a little problem, but I can't say what it is.

Here is the [code](https://github.com/JeremieGauthier/AI_Exercices/blob/master/Atari_Breakout/DQN_Breakout_with_ptan.py)

It is a problem with the replay memory.

```
try:
    next_states = torch.tensor(batch[3], dtype=torch.float32) 
except:
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

The problem is located where are those lines.  `set_trace()` is use to pop-up an interactive shell. From there, if I run `for i in range(batch_size): print(batch[3][i].shape)`, I obtained this output

```
ipdb> for i in range(32): print(batch[3][i].shape)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
(4, 84, 84)
*** AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

How can I improve that code to avoid such error?

Comment: This question is more appropriate for Stack Overflow (because this is just a programming issue). I will migrate it to SO and provide a formal answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem. You're trying to call `shape` on `None`, so, in your code, some variable `a` is `None` and you are calling `shape` on it, i.e. `a.shape`. This is one of the most common errors in programming!

In your `for` loop

```
for i in range(32): 
    print(batch[3][i].shape)
```

at some point, `batch[3][i]` is `None`, so you will have to figure out what `batch[3]` contains and why it is `None`.

See the discussion here https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54070403#54070403.

Comment: @jgauth I will try to have a look at your code a bit later, but clearly the problem in `batch[3]`. You're filling it with `None` at some point.

Comment: @jgauth I suggest you start printing the iteration number `i`. Maybe `batch[3]` contains less than 32 numbers.

Comment: @jgauth Why do you think the problem is with `ptan`. If I have a little bit of time later, I will try to have a look at your code more closely, but now I can't. Maybe try to use a debugger.

Comment: @jgauth What exact code do I need to execute to get your exact error?